# Why is friction force is not considered as centripetal force?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics

This is a solved example in my text book"Engineering mechanics dynamics. R.C.Hibbeler" :

The 3 kg disk is attached to the end of a cord.  The other end of the cord is attached to a ball and socket joint located at the center of the platform.  If the platform rotates rapidly,  and the disk is placed on it and released from rest,  determine the time it takes for the disk to reach a spead great enough to break the cord.  The maximum tension the cord can sustain is 100 N..  And the coefficient of the kinetic friction between the disk and the platform is 0.1

when the free body diagram of  the particle was drawn,  the friction force was considered in the tangential direction,,  but it wasn't considered in the normal direction(tension was only considered) why?  I was expecting that there is kinetic friction in the normal direction,  since the disk is moving relative to the platform.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because friction resists either a centrifugal force or a centripetal force - ie friction opposes any motion.

Comment: This is in static analysis but in the dynamic analysis, the friction force will be in the same direction of the motion.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool Since when?  I can't think of any scenarios where that is true.

Comment: @JMac The kinetic friction *forces* (plural!) always act in the same direction as the relative motion of the bodies. By Newton's third law, the two forces (one on each body) have opposite signs, of course. In complicated problems, it's usually easier to work with a consistent sign convention and some negative magnitudes, rather than drawing free body diagrams that look like "Custer's last stand" with arrows pointing every which way.

Comment: @alephzero It acts in the _opposite_ direction of the motion of the body.  The force on one body is in the same direction as the movement of _the other body_.

Comment: Do friction forces on a car act to accelerate it or slow it down?

Comment: @SolarMike Depends on what parts of the car you're talking about.  There are plenty of friction forces on the internals that obviously slow it down.  I assume you're more getting at the friction from the tires; which is obviously what makes the car move.  The thing is, even in that case, you are actually spinning the contact surface _backwards_ and generating a friction in the forward direction.

Comment: Actually considering the air resistance which is the largest contributor above about 40mph...